# Bootstrap's collapsible navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My Bootstrap collapsible menu isn't working. I can't figure out where is my problem?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="#top">the company</a>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

    </div>
    <div class="menu" id="#myNavbar" class="collapse  navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="myNavbar">
      <li class="scrollable"><a href="#about" class="active" class="scrollable">About me</a></li>
      <li class="scrollable"><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li class="scrollable"><a href="#contact">Contact Me</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Collapses correctly here: http://jsbin.com/miyabinodu/edit?html,css,output

Comment: What isn't working about it? On Stack Overflow it's good to give specific details.

Comment: Can you post all of the code on the page?

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate attributes for *class* in multiple divs as well as multiple `data-toggle="collapse"` & `data-target="myNavbar"`.

Also your target ID has the # in it, it should not: `id="#myNavbar"` should be `id="myNavbar"`

**Validate** your HTML and refer to the refer to the [Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)
[image]

**Working Example:**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#top">the company</a>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div id="myNavbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse menu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active scrollable"><a href="#about">About me</a>
        </li>
        <li class="scrollable"><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="scrollable"><a href="#contact">Contact Me</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> The problem was with:
>
> - Your collapse navbar hierarchy.
> - The div where you used `menu` class.
> - Syntax

- The anchor tag: `<a class="navbar-brand" href="#top">the company</a>` should come after `button` tag.
- And the menu class should be used along with other classes: `<div id="myNavbar" class="menu collapse  navbar-collapse">`, instead of `<div class="menu" id="#myNavbar" class="collapse  navbar-collapse">`
- `<div id="#myNavbar"` should be changed to `<div id="myNavbar"`. Remove the `#`, you don't need it while adding `id` to the div.
- And final issue: Don't use  `data-toggle="collapse" data-target="myNavbar">` again in the `ul` tag. Just use `<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">`

Try running the code snippet below and don't forget to include Bootstrap and jQuery libraries in your webpage. Cheers!

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="#top">the company</a>
    </div>
    <div id="myNavbar" class="menu collapse  navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="scrollable"><a href="#about" class="active" class="scrollable">About me</a></li>
      <li class="scrollable"><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li class="scrollable"><a href="#contact">Contact Me</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```